# Adding another data file on a separate hard drive Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, mdf

I have ran into an issue with one of our Sql Server databases where we have hit a file size limit as the partition is Master Boot Record. We are currently at a little less than 2tb. Now I am looking for the best options and I think adding a 2nd data file on a separate hard drive may be the best option with little to no downtime? Now my question is how does sql server know not to write to the original data file location? Also, I am assuming there wouldn't be any downtime as I have added data files in my test environments with no issues.

Thanks

Comment: so many articles. so little google. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189563.aspx https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4345/understanding-how-sql-server-stores-data-in-data-files/

Comment: My title may be a little miss leading but I already know how to add a 2nd data file. My concern is does the original data file still grow after adding the 2nd data file?

Comment: if the file has autogrowth turned off, and a max size is defined, then it will not grow. https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/sql-server-database-growth-and-autogrowth-settings/